# Polish characters encoding with UTF-8 doesn't work only in one JSP file

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, utf-8

I have unbelievable problem with JSP file encoding. **Only one** of many our JSP files has broken UTF-8 encoding. We are using Polish characters like ł, ż, etc.

I have UTF encoding set in Eclipse in this places:

> > Preferences -> General -> Content Types -> Text -> JSP -> Default Encoding -> UTF-8
> >
> > Preferences -> Web -> JSP Files
> >
> > Preferences -> General -> Workspace

My JSP file looks like this:

```
<%@ page import="main.tables.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Szczegóły użytkownika</title>
<style>
    <%@include file="../../../WebDevelopment/css/style.css"%>
    <%@include file="../../../WebDevelopment/css/bootstrap.min.css"%>
</style>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 ...
</body>
</html>
```

Also I tried changing encoding in notepad and setting it in servlet. I used this lines:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Anyone has similar problem only in one JSP file?

Comment: You didn't actually state what is not working or what symptoms happen. If this isn't generating XML content, take out the XML header.

Comment: @nitind XML header was added after all. I was trying everything and added that. Problem is that I have all needed declaration of characters encoding and on only this page characters are displayed incorrectly. Like this: "Szczegó?y u?ytkownika"

Comment: Are they displayed incorrectly in Eclipse or in the browser?

Comment: They are displayed incorrectly only in browser. In Eclipse are normal Polish characters.

Comment: @nitind Thanks for your help. I resolved this issue answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

After long troubleshooting I decided to recreate servlet and JSP file on my machine. Originally one of my colleague created it on his own computer.

So **I created new servlet and JSP in my Eclipse with properly set encoding in all places.** After that I copied doPost body and JSP html body. And that worked...

We need to look at this issue in our team. Probably key to get rid of similar problems is to set UTF-8 encoding in this places:

> Preferences -> General -> Content Types -> Text -> JSP -> Default Encoding -> UTF-8
>
> Preferences -> Web -> JSP Files
>
> Preferences -> General -> Workspace